# Read 3 bits from a bytearray

Tags: actionscript-3

I am writing a DXT5 image reader in ActionScript 3 and I need to read 16 3-bit values stored in 6 bytes in a larger bytearray. I'm a bit at a loss as to how to read this in efficiently. I've done something similar with 2 bit codes, but the odd number makes it more difficult(at least to me). Ideally the source bytearray will end with the position to the next byte after the 6 in question.

```
var values:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>(16);
var alpha_bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
data.readBytes(alpha_bytes, 0, 6);

// ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i figured out a solution - not very elegant, but it works. Basically I read 24 bits into a short and a byte and OR them together into a uint which then represents 24 bits. I then use a for loop to pull out the real values.

```
var alpha_16:uint = data.readUnsignedShort();
var alpha_8:uint = data.readUnsignedByte();

var alpha_1:uint =  (alpha_8 << 16) | alpha_16;

for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    alpha_values[j] = ( alpha_1 & ( 7 << ( 3 * j ) ) ) >> ( 3 * j )
}
```